# lookup using Maps from Data.Tree.AVL.Map in Agda

Tags: agda, agda-stdlib

I don't understand how to use the provided `Map` from Stdlib. I tried creating a `Map` from `String` to `String`, and it worked, but whenever I try using the `lookup` function I get weird errors:

This is a simplification of my code:

```
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.String
open import Data.String.Properties
open import Data.Tree.AVL.Map (<-strictTotalOrder-≈) using (Map ; singleton ; lookup)

singletonMap : Map String
singletonMap = singleton "test" "a"

test : Maybe String
test = lookup singletonMap "test"
```

I get the following error:

```
(Data.Tree.AVL.Tree <-strictTotalOrder-≈
 (Data.Tree.AVL.Value.const
  (Relation.Binary.Bundles.StrictPartialOrder.Eq.setoid
   (Relation.Binary.Bundles.StrictTotalOrder.strictPartialOrder
    <-strictTotalOrder-≈))
  String))
!=< String
when checking that the expression singletonMap has type
Relation.Binary.Bundles.StrictTotalOrder.Carrier
<-strictTotalOrder-≈
```

I'm having trouble trying to even understand what's happening, it looks like `lookup` is not expecting an argument like `singletonMap`, because the types do not match, but how can that be possible? I created it using `singleton`, and the functions have the following types (they can be seen in [Data.Tree.AVL.Map](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Tree.AVL.Map) as well):

```
singleton : Key → V → Map V
```

```
lookup : Map V → Key → Maybe V
```

They are literally the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking to the documentation of the current dev version.
In older, released versions, `lookup` takes the key first, and the `Map` second.
You should write

```
test : Maybe String
test = lookup "test" singletonMap
```

The dev version is gearing up to release a version 2.0 with breaking changes in the name of uniformity (all lookups will now have a type of the form `Container -> Key -> Val` because the type of keys may depend on the type of the container, but not the other way around).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I realize what the error was trying to say.